# Separar componentes léxicos en C#

Tags: c#, split

alguien me puede ayudar a separar los componentes de una linea empezando desde el string hasta el ";"?
el resultado debe de ser un arreglo que contenga:

```
//Resultado esperado
string []{"string","cadena","=","+-*/hola cadena1","+","cadena 2","123456",";"};

 //cadena a separar empezando desde el string hasta el ;
 string cadena="+-*/hola cadena1"+"cadena 2" 123456;
```

he intentado con un split que divida por espacios en blanco pero me causa muchos problemas ya que intente que los operadores sean los divisores agregándoles espacios en blanco con este codigo:

```
public static string[] separador(this string cadena)
    {
        string[] operadores = { "!=","==","+", "-", "/", "^", "=", "?", "¿", ";", "*", "{", "}", 
        "&&", "||" };
        foreach (string x in operadores)
        {
            cadena = cadena.Replace(x, " " + x + " ");
        }
        return cadena.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
```

pero si nos damos cuenta la cadena entre comillas contiene espacios en blanco y operadores.

```
"+-*/hola cadena1"+ "cadena 2"
```

entonces también me dividirá lo que esta entre comillas entonces me arrojaria como resultado un arreglo:

```
//resultado generado
string []{"string","cadena","=","+","-","*","/","hola","cadena1","+","cadena","2","123456",";"};
```

Comment: Lo vas a tener que dividir a mano... con un split, cada vez que encuentres un replace valido vas a encontrar 10000 invalidos... deberias cortar tu string cada vez que encuentres un caracter de corte, a mano, teniendo en cuenta los otros caracteres (por ejemplo no cortar si estas entre comillas)...